# Standing idle while a couple is cuddling or kissing

Tags: expressions

What's the expression for the awkward situation in which I'm going out with a couple all by myself and I end up standing idle while they are cuddling or kissing?

Comment: Two's company, three's a crowd.

Comment: It's called "being disrespected"

Answer (score 6):

A common expression is: ***be [a fifth wheel or a third wheel](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+third+wheel):***

> A fifth wheel or a third wheel in a situation is someone who is not needed or wanted there. As a single person, you're somewhat of a third wheel when traveling with couples.
>
> - *I just wanted to feel like part of the family instead of a fifth wheel. I wanted to feel like I belonged*!
>
>   Note: A fifth wheel on a car or a third wheel on a bicycle would be unnecessary.

(Collins COBUILD Idioms Dictionary)

Also:

***[play gooseberry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/play-gooseberry)***
or  *feel like a gooseberry* (uk informal)
​

> to be an unwanted third person who is present when two other people, especially two people having a romantic relationship, want to be alone

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Origin of the expression “[play gooseberry](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-pla2.htm)” from World Wide Words

Answer (score 0):

This is called being a **third wheel** (sometimes 'fifth wheel').

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+third+wheel

Here's an article from the other perspective.

https://www.glamour.com/story/5-ways-to-help-you-deal-with-a